# PhoneStateListener events stop receiving sometime

Tags: android

My application process incoming/outgoing calls and shows some UI. 
So I use PhoneStateListener to listen changes  such as  CALL_STATE_IDLE , CALL_STATE_RINGING ,CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK. on receiving call to my BroacastReceiver  for incoming/outgoing call.

Most of the time things work properly.  But sometimes my application does not receive events of PhoneStateListener and hence it is not able to change/clear  UI.  From user feedback this typically occurs on HTC Hero. But I have came across this issue sometime on other devices also.

My first guess is that android is killing my application in midway during call due to memory requirement. If so, is there any way to ensure that android does not my kill application under such situation .

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 1):

> If so, is there any way to ensure that
>   android does not my kill application
>   under such situation.

No, there is not.

You may wish to consider switching away from `PhoneStateListener` to listening for `ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED` broadcast `Intents`. That way, your code does not need to stay running.

Comment: The issue with ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED is that , it will not have original application context . So I won't be able to interact (change/dismiss) with UI which is still visible to the user. 
Or do you think  that, since UI is still visible original application context is still available and intent received from ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGE broadcast will be able to interact with UI ?

Comment: "So I won't be able to interact (change/dismiss) with UI which is still visible to the user." You said your application is being closed to free up memory. At that point, you do not have a UI. Android will not close up the foreground activity due to memory reasons. So, if you are not receiving PhoneStateListener updates from a foreground activity, memory consumption is not your problem. If you do not have a foreground activity, then there is no UI that is visible to the user.

Comment: My activity is not foreground as it has to work during incoming/outgoing call. I use toast/notification area for UI.

Comment: In that case, then you will "be able to interact (change/dismiss) with UI which is still visible to the user", insofar as you can raise or dismiss Notification objects from the BroadcastReceiver, or show Toasts, from a BroadcastReceiver.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue: after a few hours it seemed that the listening was dropped. To solve this, I created a `Timer` that repeats every 30 minutes the call for listening: create a `Timer` that calls for a `TimerTask` class inside the service which contains the listening requests and make the `Timer` call for the TimerTask class every X milliseconds. That worked for me.